# ActiveMQ: Topics that can't be removed

Tags: java, activemq-classic

Our application allows users to create ActiveMQ topics and subscribe to them. All subscribers are created as durable subscribers. The ActiveMQ broker is embedded in the app and started when the app starts.

Testing has revealed the following problem:

1. If a topic is created, but never subscribed to, it can be removed through the Broker operations in JConsole or via our app's code using "BrokerView.removeTopic(String)". In either of these cases, the topic is removed from the JConsole topic listing and it's not seen again.
2. If the topic gets durable subscribers that are then unsubscribed (so there are no subscribers and no messages), it can still be removed, as above, using JConsole or the app itself. The topic disappears from the JConsole Topic listing. However, when I restart the app, the topic reappears. I call it a "zombie topic". This scenario repeats no matter how many times I try to delete the topic.

I suspect that the KahaDB is persisting these topics and reinstating them, but I've been unable to find anything that describes this specific behavior or what I might do to modify it.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Version? A similar bug was fixed  some versions back: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4970

Comment: @Petter Nordlander  Sorry for not including the version.  ActiveMQ version 5.12.0 - K. Monroe